# How to generate yii2 form with data coming from two models, but need to save changes to one of them

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, checkbox, yii2

Logged in users in my system can chose favorite CPV ID's. CPV's are main product of application, and they are stored in table `cpv`. Some columns in 
`cpv` table are : `id`, `title`, `url`.

Now I need to allow users to check which CPV's they like, and store/use that. I have formed `user_cpv` table that should store user and cpv id relation. Fields are `id`, `user_id`, `cpv_id`.

So first I would display all CPV's for the logged in user, but also, I would give him check boxes next to each of them so he can chose 3 favorite ones. Like this:

[image]

Before I continue I need to ask one subquestion: how can I display checkboxes without this label pulled from my model ( Cpv ID ) ?

To continue: so in my index action of my controller, I am pulling cpv data from `Cpv` model. But also I guess that I need to pull stored values from `user_cpv` table, because for each user there, there can be up to 3 `cpv_id` stored as his favorites. I guess that I need that information if I want to mark some of the `Cpv ID` as checked. So if user has `cpv_id` in `user_cpv` table, those ids are marked as checked in the whole list displayed in the table that I showed you.

The image above displays the index action result ( I do not use any widgets ). I want to allow user to check some of these checkboxes and save that into `user_cpv` table. This is some of the code in my index view:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered my-favourites">
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['action' => ['user-cpv/create']]); ?>
    <?php foreach ($values as $data): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $data['cpvId'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $form->field($model, 'cpv_id')->checkbox() ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</table>
```

Here, I am stuck. When I am displaying CPV's ( lets take just their ids like in picture ), how to mark as checked those that are stored in `user_cpv` relation table ? Here is some rough dirty pseudo code that I have in my mind :

```
actionIndex() {

    // pull data from cpv table
    $model = CPV::find();

    // pull data from user_cpv
    $relation = UserCpv::find();

    // somehow find those that match and maybe pass that info to view ?
}
```

Then in my view, how to set cpv_ids found in `user_cpv` as checked, if this is the checkbox render method ? :

`<?= $form->field($model, 'cpv_id')->checkbox() ?>`

And at last, if user check some other boxes, need to validate that he has chosen maximum of 3 boxes, and finally save that.

Can someone help me with this? Any help is appreciated, guidelines, example codes... Maybe my idea with `user_cpv` relation table is wrong ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

- For this first you need to define a relation in cpv model relationship with cpv-user model. In cpv model you will define relation (sample for relation model).

  public function getUsercpv(){
           return $this->hasMany(UserCpv::className(), ['id' => 'cpv_id']);
           }
- now in controller you pull data from CPV model with relation

  // pull data from cpv table
  $model = CPV::find()->joinWith('usercpv');
- In view you can get user-cpv data using  $data->usercpv, and can loop throug

Comment: I am displaying data, need to make checkboxed whose values ( checked or not ) will be based on values from related table. I think that you have not understood what I am trying here.

Comment: use html helper  like <?=html::checkbox();?